# Trying to update a record from within an Index using Best In Place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to update a record from an index using either jQuery alone or the in-place editor "Best In Place". Not getting the checkbox and losing formatting on my `<THEAD>` row. I was using [this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing) as a guide but when I used the syntax on the checkbox Ryan used I got an error saying:

Update: Ruby 1.8.7

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'

**Code--**

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.tablednd_0_5.js
//= require jquery.tablesorter.js
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
```

comments, crb_agenda and pre_release_agenda coffee scripts:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

comments_controller.rb#update

```
  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
        Comment.add_comment_to_jira_ticket("MCTEST-293",@comment.user_comments)
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, :notice => 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @comment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

CRB Agenda index.html.erb up to the td with the best_in_place helper (and yes it is a mess)

```
<table id="main_agenda" class="agenda_table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Hide?</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th title="Sub tasks due in the next three days">Sub-tasks</th>
            <th>Project name</th>
            <th>Change element</th>
            <th>Issue type</th>
            <th>Key</th>
            <th>Issue links</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
            <th>Assignee</th>
            <th>Reporter</th>
            <th>Dev Lead / Resource Mgr.</th>
            <th>Planned Rel. Dt</th>
            <th>Due Dt</th>
            <th>Approval Source</th>
            <th>SOX</th>
            <th>Dev</th>
            <th>QA</th>
            <th>SQE</th>
            <th>ST</th>
            <th>UX</th>
            <th>App QA</th>
            <th>Systest QA</th>
            <th>SQE Test</th>
            <th>Dependencies</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @crb_agendas.each do |crb_agenda| %>
              <% @sub_tasks = [] %>
              <% @linked_issues = SubTask.where(:pdms_key => crb_agenda.key).all %>
              <% @pdms_comment = Comment.where(:jira_key => crb_agenda.key).order("updated_at DESC").first %>
              <tr class="<%= cycle('a_row','b_row') %>" id="<%= crb_agenda.id %>">
                <% SubTask.select("`key`").where(:pdms_key => crb_agenda.key).where("`key` LIKE 'CR%'").where("due_date <= '#{@date_cutoff.to_s}'").each do |sub_key| @sub_tasks << sub_key.key end %>
                <td class="mincell" title="This PDMS has an upcoming iCR on the Pre-Release Agenda"><%= if (@sub_tasks & @icr_key_list).any? == true then "*" end %></td>
                <td><%= best_in_place @pdms_comment, :do_not_show, :type => :check_box, :collection => %w[No Yes] %></td>

  end
```

Does that cover everything?

Comment: what version of Ruby? (`ruby -v` from command line)

Comment: @sethvargo Ruby 1.8.7; Just added it to the main post too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up abandoning Best in Place and creating the answer I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914646/rails-3-1-need-to-do-in-place-editing-on-an-index-page/8980805#8980805)