# best_in_place with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I want to use [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) for a has_many_association like this:

```
<% @offer.locations.each do |location| %>
  <%= best_in_place location, :name, :path => offer_path(@offer) %>
<% end %>
```

offers_controller.rb

```
  def update
    if @offer.update(offer_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json   { respond_with_bip(@offer) }
      end
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end


private

  def offer_params
    params.require(:offer).permit(:template_id, :client_id, :partner_id, :status,
    locations_attributes: [:id, :name, :address, :_destroy,
    surfaces_attributes: [:id, :size, :_destroy,
    services_attributes: [:id, :name, :price, :unit, :description, :service_id,    :_destroy]
      ]])
  end

  def find_offer
   @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
  end
```

But when I try editting the location field, the location id has the same id with the offer's id.
I am also using the cocoon gem for nested forms.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: What's your goal or expected result?

Comment: I am doing this in a view rendered from another controller than offers. I want to be able to edit the location field. It is editable, but I get this in my logs:     ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty

Comment: Parameters: {"offer_location"=>{"name"=>"Bucuresti"}, "id"=>"1"}, but 1 is the id of the offer and I don't know how should I pass both parameteres to make this work.

Comment: I have not used `best_in_place` however I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914646/rails-3-1-need-to-do-in-place-editing-on-an-index-page/8980805#8980805 can help you

Comment: Could you please post the controller action for handling the `best_in_place` editing that the `offer_path(@offer)` route points to?